# Is there a way of dynamically attributing the description annotation in testNG?

Tags: java, testng

```
    private String GIVEN = "";
    private String WHEN = "";
    private String THEN = "";


    @Test(description = GIVEN + WHEN + THEN)
    public void test() {

            GIVEN += "blah blah blah";
            WHEN += "blah blah blah";
            THEN += "blah blah blah";

    }
```

I want to do it this way b/c I want to add the descriptions in the methods used within tests. This way I avoid comments and can keep details up to date as tests change.

For instance, I will call this method within a test and update the given at the same time:

```
public void method(){
     code;
     GIVEN += "this code is doing this blah blah";
}
```

Values can only be a constants so I'm stumped at this point.

Comment: Even if this is possible it will require custom test runner. Then you have to store your description somewhere in static variable and update it in runner. I strongly suggest you not to follow this path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ITestResult report = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
report.getMethod().setDescription("Whatever you would like to say");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Define the parameters on TestNG.xml**

```
<parameter name="blah blah blah" />
<parameter name="when" value="blah blah blah" />  
<parameter name="then" value="blah blah blah" />
```

**And then can use in your test case like below**

```
  private String GIVEN = "";
   private String WHEN = "";
   private String THEN = "";
         
    @Test
         @Parameters({"given","when","then"})
            public void test() {
        
                    GIVEN += given;
                    WHEN += when;
                    THEN += then;
        
            }
```